# VueJS environment variables not usable in main.js

Tags: vue.js, environment-variables, vuejs3

I have a `main.js` file in my app, and I use something called XXX (the name is not relevant here). I try to use environment variables to configure XXX:

```
app
  .use(XXX, {
    host: process.env.VUE_APP_XXX_URL,
    siteId: process.env.VUE_APP_XXX_SITE_ID,
    router,
  })
```

But it doesn't work. When I use the real values, it works like a charm. **I think I can't use environment variables in my `main.js` file**. What would be the good solution?

PS: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#using-env-variables-in-client-side-code doesn't work either

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you try with `import.meta.env.YOUR_VARIABLE`? I guess you're using Vite and not webpack: https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html#env-files

Comment: I don't use Vite and I don't have the impressionI'm using webpack because I can't find it anywhere in the sources.

Comment: You use one or the other. How did you created the project? What do you see when your project is running (in the CLI)?

Comment: I see things like `Starting development server` ` xx% building modules` `chunk asset processing`. I think I see webpack but it goes too fast. I don't remember how I created the project, I began with using files from an old project, then upgrading the npm dependencies little by little.

Comment: make sure to use VUE_APP_* as a prefix for your .env vars and restart the build/run process when changing the values here. In my case I had a typo in the prefix!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dotenv` npm package for custom environment variables.

#### Usage

Create a `.env` file in the root of your project:

```
VUE_APP_XXX_URL="Your URL"
VUE_APP_XXX_SITE_ID="Your Site ID"
```

As early as possible in your application (For example in `main.ts` or `main.js`), import and configure dotenv:

```js
require('dotenv').config()
```

After that you can now get your custom environment variable in `process.env` object.

```js
process.env.VUE_APP_XXX_URL; // Your URL
process.env.VUE_APP_XXX_SITE_ID; // Your Site ID
```

Read more in the official package.: [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)

Comment: Not really needed since it's baked in.

Comment: Actually I already use process.env.VUE_APP_XXX elsewhere in my components and it works perfectly. But in `main.js`, for some reason it doesn't.